# Embedding matlab plot in pdf for printing: Sizes

Tags: image, matlab, latex, resize, figure

I'm currently creating my figures in matlab to embed themvia latex into a pdf for later printing. I save the figures and save them via the script [export_fig](https://sites.google.com/site/oliverwoodford/software/export_fig)! Now I wonder which is the best way to go:

- Which size of the matlab figure window to chose
- Which `-m` option to take for the script? It will change the resolution and the size of the image...

I'm wondering about those points in regards to the following two points:

1. When chosing the figure-size bigger, there are more tickmarks shown and the single point markers are better visible
2. When using a small figure and using a big `-m` option, I still have only *some* tickmarks
3. When I generate a image which is quite huge (e.g. resolution 300 and still 2000*2000px) and than embed it into the document: Does this than look ugly? Will this be embedded in a nice scaling mode or is it the same ugliness as if you upload a 1000*1000px image onto a homepage and embed it via the widht and height tags in html -> the browser displays it quite ugly because the browser doesn't do a `real` resize. So it looks unsharp and ugly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MATLAB plots are internally described as [vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics), and PDF files are also described using vector graphics.  Rendering the plot to a raster format is a bad idea, because you end up having to choose resolution and end up with bigger files.

Just save the plot to [EPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) format, which can be directly embedded into a PDF file using `latex`.   I usually save my MATLAB plots for publication using:

```
saveas(gcf, 'plot.eps', 'epsc');
```

and embed them directly into my latex file using:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{plot.eps}
```

Then, you only need to choose the proportion of the line the image is to take (in this case, 70%).

**Edit**: IrfanView and others (XnView) don't display EPS very well.  You can open them in Adobe Illustrator to get a better preview of what it looks like.  I always insert my plots this way and they always look exactly the same in the PDF as in MATLAB.

One bonus you also get with EPS is that you can actually specify a font size so that the text is readable even when you resize the image in the document.

As for the number of ticks, you can look at the [axes properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html) in the MATLAB documentation.  In particular, the `XTick` and `YTick` properties are very useful manually controlling how many ticks appear no matter what the window resolution is.

**Edit (again)**: If you *render* the image to a *raster format* (such as PNG), it is preferable to choose the exact same resolution as the one used in the document.  Rendering a large image (by using a big window size) and making it small in the PDF will yield bad results mainly because the size of the text will scale directly with the size of the image.  Rendering a small image will obviously make for a very bad effect because of stretching.

That is why you should use a vector image format.  However, the default MATLAB settings for figures produce some of the same problems as raster images: text size is not specified as a font size and the number of ticks varies with the window size.

To produce optimal plots in the final render, follow the given steps:

1. Set the figure's font size to a decent setting (e.g. 11pt)
2. Render the plot
3. Decide on number of ticks to get a good effect and set the ticks manually
4. Render the image to color EPS

In MATLAB code, this should look somewhat like the following:

```
function [] = nice_figure ( render )
    %
      % invisible figure, good for batch renders.
    f = figure('Visible', 'Off');
      % make plots look nice in output PDF.
    set(f, ...
        'DefaultAxesFontSize', 11, ...
        'DefaultAxesLineWidth', 0.7, ...
        'DefaultLineLineWidth', 0.8, ...
        'DefaultPatchLineWidth', 0.7);
      % actual plot to render.
    a = axes('Parent', f);
      % show whatever it is we need to show.
    render(a);
      % save file.
    saveas(f, 'plot.eps', 'epsc');
      % collect garbarge.
    close(f);
end
```

Then, you can draw some fancy plot using:

```
function [] = some_line_plot ( a )
    %
      % render data.
    x = -3 : 0.001 : +3;
    y = expm1(x) - x - x.^2;
    plot(a, x, y, 'g:');
    title('f(x)=e^x-1-x-x^2');
    xlabel('x');
    ylabel('f(x)');
      % force use of 'n' ticks.
    n = 5;
    xlimit = get(a, 'XLim');
    ylimit = get(a, 'YLim');
    xticks = linspace(xlimit(1), xlimit(2), n);
    yticks = linspace(ylimit(1), ylimit(2), n);
    set(a, 'XTick', xticks);
    set(a, 'YTick', yticks);
end
```

And render the final output using:

```
nice_figure(@some_line_plot);
```

With such code, you don't need to worry about the window size at all.  Notice that I haven't even showed the window for you to play with its size.  Using this code, I always get beautiful output and small EPS and PDF file sizes (much smaller than when using PNG).

The *only* thing this solution does *not* address is adding more ticks when the plot is made larger in the latex code, but that can't be done anyways.

Comment: The eps format isn't very well displayed. Try out the export_fig script which gets you good results as png files. The look nicer. And a good resolution is automatically provided by the script.I was rather concerned about the size to export the images with. When I set the figure window too big before exporting, I have more ticks but when displaying it in smaller size in the pdf, the text will be very small too.Thus it's perhaps better to have a smaller original fig-window and export it with a higher resolution.When embedding it than, I have fewer ticks but a greater font-size.Thats the question

Comment: Or is the eps image file only displayed ugly when opening it in irfan view to display it? But which size do you take for your figure window because this WILL defintly influence the exported figure in eps format since the smaller you have your matlab figure window, the fewer ticks you will have in the file and the greater the font-size will be compared to the rest of the plot. And that's also part of my question! Rather than the format itself!

Comment: @Col: I added more info to address your extra questions.

Comment: @ColHeather: use Ghostscript/GSView instead of IrfanView to display EPS: http://www.ghostscript.com/

Comment: Thanks you both. @Amro: In Gsview it doesn't look nice either...@André: The question remains about the size of the figure window before exporting it. It will definitly make a difference: Let's say I set the figure size to something like 1000*1000px, I can show more tick marks (because there's more space). But when I export it and embed it to my document in a small size (0.7*textwidth or so), the fonzsize will look unsharp because it's somehow 'compressed'. And it's the same about the rest of plot like label, ticks and also the legend, because the fontsizes wont get bigger  when choosing ...

Comment: ... huge figure sizes. The contrast would be a very small figure window of 100*100px where I can thus ONLY show one tick per axes because of the small space. When I export it I will only have one tick, even if I export it with a scaling of 3x. Thus: In general, the figure window WILL have a big influence. Further I wonder if it's always the best habit to export to an image as big as possible and than embed it to the latex document with a much smaller size? Or will this make the image look unsharp also because the image itself isn't completely resized physically as a new file...!?

Comment: @Col: I don't think you read what I wrote.  You can manually control how many ticks appear in the output **absolutely independently** from the the size of the window.  I posted example code for how I generate my EPS image output.  This should clarify the issue.  The answer to the last question is no, see my 2nd edit for details.

Comment: OH I must have missed the last sentence "no matter what the window resolution is.". Probably it was because I thought `oh I know about those axis-options already`: Sorry! I will read your edit now carefully! Edit: Okay thanks for your answer again. I will try it out soon and than tell you about my results!